# Multiple vuex store in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I am trying to implement a micro frontend architecture in my application. I am having a common store where I have all the data which are commonly used across all the services. In one of the service I am trying to import the common store and use it globally, but I was not able to access it.

example:

in main.js I am trying the below code:

```
import Vue from "vue";
// Trying to import the common store
import commonStore from "../../common/src/store"
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store/store";

new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      commonStore
});
```

In App.vue i was trying to the below, but i am unable to access it.

```
mounted(){
  console.log(this.$commonStore);
}
```

Is there any way, I could use multiple stores in vue.

Comment: have you read about [VueX Modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html)? I think this is what you mean by 'multiple stores'. Why do you need the store in the main.js? Isn't it enough if you only import the store in the individual components?

Comment: @wittgenstein in `micro frontend architecture application` there are many main.js files

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looking for `Modules`. In Vuex you can define independent store modules:

```js
const commonStore = {
  state: () => ({ a: 1 }),

};

const globalStore = {
  state: () => ({ a: 2 }),
};

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    commonStore: commonStore,
    globalStore: globalStore
  }
})

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
});
```

Then you can access module store via:

```js
mounted() {
  console.log(this.$store.state.commonStore.a); // => 1
  console.log(this.$store.state.globalStore.a); // => 2
}
```